# Retrieve all fields when using Agregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my mongodb database, I have only 2 collections  : Clients and TypeClients.

Each document on Clients has an idTypeClient. (I don't want to use embedded documents, because I want to manage TypeClient separately).

## Clients collection :

```
db.clients.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("644d07b750c766f2e55a99d4"),
    name: 'Apple',
    website: 'http://www.apple.com',
    idTypeClient: '644d01b7ad65ba68ad69da4c'
  }
]
```

## Type Client collection :

```
db.type_clients.find()

[

  {

    _id: ObjectId("644d01b7ad65ba68ad69da4c"),

    label: 'Type B',

    __v: 0

  }

]
```

I heard that I need to do this :

```
db.clients.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
          "idTypeClient": {
            "$toObjectId": "$idTypeClient"
          }
        }
      },
  {$lookup:{from:'type_clients',localField:'idTypeClient',foreignField:"_id",as:'typeClient'}}
]);
```

But I got :

[

```
 {
    _id: ObjectId("644d07b750c766f2e55a99d4"),
    idTypeClient: ObjectId("644d01b7ad65ba68ad69da4c"),
    typeClient: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("644d01b7ad65ba68ad69da4c"),
        label: 'Type B',
        __v: 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to also get all the fields from the Clients collections (clients.name and clients.website)

Thanks

Comment: Use `$addFields` instead of `$project`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example as suggested by Charchit Kapoor in the comments:

[example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1s1QmcvY_fL)

P.S.
Keeping idTypeClient field as object and creating index on that fields is expected to add some performance improvement in your query ...